# The best way to print long text in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new in react native and I want to know which would be the best way to print long text in my app, because I making an note bloc to start, the problem now is that I'm printing the content inside a textinput with this values:

```
<TextInput multiline = {true} ></TextInput>
```

The input obviously will go down because of multiline but I want also insert img into it, do something like this:

[image]

Add the img make a break line and continue writing, if I do it in this way:

```
<TextInput><Image></Image></TextInput>
```

I get this:

[image]

It doesn't make a break line and when I type something:

[image]

Somebody told me to use flexbox, but really don't know how implement it, thanks if you could help me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do `<TextInput><Image /></TextInput>` it will make the both the TextInput and Image be in a row. What you wanted is for it to be in a column.

So, you can do it this way:

```
<View>
 <TextInput 
   placeholder= 'Helooooo' />
 <Image source={{uri:'https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg'}}  style={{height:60, width:60}}/>
</View>
```

[image]